# What happens if $U\in \textit{P}(X)$ is always either closed or open

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space s.t. $\forall U\in \textit{P}(X)$, $U$ is either open or closed (or both only in the cases $U=X, U=\varnothing$).

What can we say about $X$?

I found this example of such a space: Let $X$ a set. Fix $u\in X$, and then say that $U\in \textit{P}(X)$ is closed $\iff$ $u\in U$ or $U=\varnothing$.

Note that in the above example I could substitute "open" with "closed" and it would still work.

My conjecture (which is poorly founded) is that all such topological spaces are of the above forms.

Comment: $X=\{0,1\}$ and $T=\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{0,1\}\}$. Then every set except $\{1\}$ is open, so $\{1\}$ is closed, and neither $\{0\}$ nor $\{1\}$ are clopen.

Comment: Yes, and that fits my conjecture ($u=1$)

Comment: Consider the set $\{0,1,2\}$ and the topology: $$\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,2\}, \{0,1,2\}\}$$ Now $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are both closed, neither contains the other, and every element of the power set is either open or closed.

Comment: How do you quantify over $u$? What you wrote doesn't really parse properly. Because if it just means what it says, then $u=0$ doesn't satisfy this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will update my question to include this "symmetrical case"

Comment: Isn't this just saying that the opens (without $\emptyset$) form an ultrafilter in $P(X)$ and then your conjecture would probably be something that says that all ultrafilters are principal (and that is where you get to say something, Asaf)

Comment: Thinking some more about it, ultrafilters are just a specific example of such a topology. Still, non-principal ones are probably still going to be a counterexample to whatever the conjecture precisely is.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure that you can translate the problem in the language of ultrafilters like that

Comment: When you write "Let $u\in X$" then you are saying that this is true for *all* $u\in X$. In other words, $X$ is trivial (or indiscrete), which is clearly false as the two examples you've received in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, I'll correct it in order to make it clearer

Comment: If I understand the example correctly, that woul imply that {2} is open, as the intersection of {1,2} and {0,2}

Comment: @LucioTanzini Your update (the example that clearly disproves your conjecture) does not disprove your conjecture. Consider $U = \{2n \mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ the set of even numbers. This is clearly a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but its complement is definitely not closed. Nor is it open. This is not an example where every subset is either open or closed.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: @LucioTanzini I believe the conjecture is true now that you allow the fixed element to be either the basis for open or closed sets, but I have not thought how it might be proven.

Comment: Do you know the term "filter"?

Comment: Yes, and the term ultrafilter as well, even tough I'm not very experienced with those concepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3088994/4280) is about so-called "door spaces" which is the name for a topological space where every subset is open or closed (like a door). It gives a link to a paper that proves there are three types of *connected* door spaces: included point topologies (there is a point so that $O$ is open iff $p \in O$ or $O$ is empty), excluded point topologies (the same with closed instead of open, as you name) and one based of a free (non-principal) ultrafilter on $X$. These objects only exist under a form of the axiom of choice (they're not "constructive").

Answer (score 1):

Mark Kamsma's comment answers your question. I figured I'd expand on it, since you seem to be ignoring it.

Let $F$ be an ultrafilter on a set $X$. Recall the definition of an [ultrafilter on a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Special_case:_ultrafilter_on_the_powerset_of_a_set). An ultrafilter on $X$ is a nonempty collection $F$ of subsets of $X$ such that

> 1. $\varnothing\not \in F$,
> 2. If $A\in F$ and $A\subseteq B$, then $B\in F$.
> 3. If $A,B\in F$, then $A\cap B\in F$.
> 4. For all $A\subseteq X$, either $A\in F$ or $A^C\in F$.

Then the collection $\tau = F\cup \{\varnothing\}$ is a topology for $X$ satisfying the condition that for every nonempty proper subset $\varnothing \subsetneq U\subsetneq X$, exactly one of $U$ and $U^C$ is in $\tau$.

Being a topology follows from properties 2 and 3 of $F$ being an ultrafilter, and satisfying the property you want follows from properties 1 and 4.

Thus a [nonprincipal ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Types_and_existence_of_ultrafilters), produces a topology which is a counterexample to your conjecture.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see. By the way this example coincides with my example in the finite case. Do you think the conjecture holds for finite spaces?

Comment: @LucioTanzini For finite spaces there are no free ultrafilters, they are all fixed. So then the ultrafilter of closed (or open) sets has a singleton intersection, and the hypothesis holds.